# ABP: FlurlHttpException covers the UserFriendlyException

Tags: xamarin, exception, aspnetboilerplate, abp, flurl

I use ABP as a server and a mobile app in Xamarin Forms.

In my Xamarin Forms I call through Flurl my api.

My api throws a UserFriendlyException. It works well through swagger UI browser.

But in my xamarin app it throws always as error 500 server FlurlHttpException.

And I can't access to my UserFriendlyException and message.

My swagger result when I call my api:

[image]

My call in my Xamarin Forms

```
 var response = await webclient
                .Request(LoginUrl)
                .PostJsonAsync(loginModel)
                .ReceiveJson<loginResultModel>();
```

It throws the flurlhttpexception. I should have the UserFriendlyException. This is the exception I have.

[image]

Comment: Please review this: https://flurl.dev/docs/error-handling/

Answer (score 0):

dynamic d = ex.GetResponseJson(); did the tricks.

thanks